# Wordpress cron-job not showing up under wp control and not working, what can I do?

Tags: wordpress, cron

I have this plugin that works when I activate it in wordpress under plugins. The problem however, it only runs once. I need it to run once a day though. Right now I would have to manually deactivate/activate it. The scheduling doesnt work. Im not sure how to fix it. Appreciate any help, thank you.

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Event Checker
Description: Automatically checks for active events that are not expired.
Version: 1.0
*/

// Register activation hook to schedule event
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );



function myplugin_custom_cron_schedule( $schedules ) {
    $schedules['myplugin_25hours'] = array(
        'interval' => 90000, // 25 hours in seconds
        'display'  => esc_html__( 'Every 25 Hours' ),
    );

    return $schedules;
}

function myplugin_activate() {

    check_active_events();

    // Schedule event to run check_active_events() every 25 hours
    if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'myplugin_check_active_events' ) ) {
        wp_schedule_event( time(), 'myplugin_25hours', 'myplugin_check_active_events' );
    }

    // Register custom time interval (25 hours)
    add_filter( 'cron_schedules', 'myplugin_custom_cron_schedule' );
}

function check_active_events() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // to retrieve all posts
  );
  
  // Instantiate the WP_Query class with the args
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  
  if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();
      $event_id = get_the_ID();
     // var_dump($event_id);      
      // Get the event start and end times
      $event_start_time = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventStartDateUTC', true);
      $event_end_time = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventEndDateUTC', true);
      
      // Calculate the time difference between the current time and the event end time
      $current_time = current_time('timestamp');
      $event_end_timestamp = strtotime($event_end_time);
      $time_diff = $event_end_timestamp - $current_time;
      //echo $time_diff;
      //var_dump( $current_time);
      //print_r ($time_diff);
      
      // Check if the event has ended
      if ($time_diff <= 0) {
        // Update the post meta for featured status and website removal
        update_post_meta($event_id, '_tribe_featured', '1');
        $event_website = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', true);
        if (!empty($event_website)) {
          update_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', '');
        }
      } else {
        // Update the post meta for featured status and website removal for ended events
        update_post_meta($event_id, '_tribe_featured', '0');
        $event_website = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', true);
        if (empty($event_website)) {
          update_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', ' ');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Restore original post data
  wp_reset_postdata();  
}


?>
```

I already installed wp control and checked the cron-jobs and nothing of this plugin showed up.

Edit:

```
<?php 
/*
Plugin Name: Event Checker
Description: Automatically checks for active events that are not expired.
Version: 1.0
*/


// Register activation hook to schedule event
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_activate' );

// Define the custom action
add_action( 'check_active_events', 'check_active_events' );

// // Schedule the action to run every hour
// if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'check_active_events' ) ) {
//  wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_ten_minutes', 'check_active_events' );
//  }

function myplugin_activate() {
    check_active_events();
    // Define the custom action
add_action( 'check_active_events', 'check_active_events' );

// Schedule the action to run every hour
if ( ! wp_next_scheduled( 'check_active_events' ) ) {
    wp_schedule_event( time(), 'every_minute', 'check_active_events' );
    }
}

// Define the function to be called by the cron job
function check_active_events() {
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'tribe_events',
    'posts_per_page' => -1, // to retrieve all posts
  );
  
  // Instantiate the WP_Query class with the args
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
  
  if ($query->have_posts()) {
    while ($query->have_posts()) {
      $query->the_post();
      $event_id = get_the_ID();
     // var_dump($event_id);      
      // Get the event start and end times
      $event_start_time = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventStartDateUTC', true);
      $event_end_time = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventEndDateUTC', true);
      
      // Calculate the time difference between the current time and the event end time
      $current_time = current_time('timestamp');
      $event_end_timestamp = strtotime($event_end_time);
      $time_diff = $event_end_timestamp - $current_time;
      //echo $time_diff;
      //var_dump( $current_time);
      //print_r ($time_diff);
      
      // Check if the event has ended
      if ($time_diff <= 0) {
        // Update the post meta for featured status and website removal
        update_post_meta($event_id, '_tribe_featured', '1');
        $event_website = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', true);
        if (!empty($event_website)) {
          update_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', '');
        }
      } else {
        // Update the post meta for featured status and website removal for ended events
        update_post_meta($event_id, '_tribe_featured', '0');
        $event_website = get_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', true);
        if (empty($event_website)) {
          update_post_meta($event_id, '_EventURL', ' ');
        }
      }
    }
  }
  
  // Restore original post data
  wp_reset_postdata();  
}


?>
```

this way it shows up in wp control but it still doesnt work

Comment: Have you figured it out ?